# Telerik UI for UWP NuGet install not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, nuget

I am trying to download the [Telerik UI for UMP](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP) NuGet package using the NuGet Package Manager (I have also tried the console) and I get the following error:

`Could not install package 'Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform 1.0.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

I have tried changing my .NETFramework version to 4.6.1 as well but it did not work. Is there something I am missing here? It shouldn't be this hard to add a NuGet package, yet here I am... Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Telerik.UI NuGet spec](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/master/BuildTools/Nuspecs.UWP/Package.UniversalWindowsPlatform.nuspec) does not support .NET. It only supports Windows Universal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you happen to know of any good open source tools to use with Winforms? I know there is [MaterialSkin](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin), but I am looking for other options if possible